# TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am a python beginner. Try to make a new button to close the window. I got the error message:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
>   line 1536, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "tk_cp_successful.py", line 138, in buttonPushed
>       self.root.destroy()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py",
>   line 1859, in destroy
>       self.tk.call('destroy', self._w) TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command:  application has been destroyed

```
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent, controller):
      self.controller = controller
      self.root = tk.Tk()
      global entry_1
      global entry_2
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      label = tk.Label(self, text="Welcome to VISA Login Page",fg="blue")
      label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

      label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")
      label_1.pack()
      label_2 = Label(self, text="Password")
      label_2.pack()
      entry_1 = Entry(self)
      entry_1.pack()
      entry_2 = Entry(self, show="*")
      entry_2.pack()
      label_1.grid(row=0, sticky=E)
      label_1.pack()
      label_2.grid(row=1, sticky=E)
      label_2.pack()
      entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
      entry_1.pack()
      entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)
      entry_2.pack()
      checkbox = Checkbutton(self, text="Keep me logged in")

      checkbox.grid(columnspan=2)
      checkbox.pack()
      logbtn = Button(self, text="Login", command = self._login_btn_clickked)
      logbtn.grid(columnspan=2)
      logbtn.pack()
      myButton = Button(self, text="Exit",command = self.buttonPushed)
      myButton.pack()

  def buttonPushed(self):
      self.root.destroy()

  def _login_btn_clickked(self):
      #print("Clicked")
      username = entry_1.get()
      password = entry_2.get()

      #print(username, password)

      if username == "test" and password == "test":
          #box.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome Tester")
          button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Please click, Welcome to login!!!",
                     command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(StartPage))
          button1.pack()
      else:
          box.showerror("Login failed", "Incorrect username")
```

Comment: I've never seen this: `logbtn.grid(columnspan=2); logbtn.pack()`, that is, "griding" a widget and immediately after "packing" it. I don't know what is the real effect, but I almost pretty sure that's not the "correct" way of doing it.

Comment: thank you for the helps. I can run on it without destroy. all work fine. once I run buttonPushed, it get error.   feel root is global, it cannot use from this class --------.self.root.destroy()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code

1. Indentation errors
2. Mixing `grid()` and `pack()`
3. Do you `import tkinter as tk` or `from tkinter import *`, i.e.
   `self.root = tk.Tk()` (`import as tk`) or
   `label_1 = Label(self, text="Username")` (`from tkinter import *`)
4. No `mainloop` in program
5. Use of global in a class is not necessary and poor style

In any case, the following modified code runs so hopefully it will help.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class LoginPage():
   def __init__(self):
      self.root=tk.Tk()
      label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Welcome to VISA Login Page",fg="blue")
      label.grid(row=0)

      label_1 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Username")
      label_2 = tk.Label(self.root, text="Password")
      self.entry_1 = tk.Entry(self.root)
      self.entry_2 = tk.Entry(self.root, show="*")
      label_1.grid(row=1, sticky="e")
      label_2.grid(row=2, sticky="e")
      self.entry_1.grid(row=1, column=1)
      self.entry_2.grid(row=2, column=1)

      ## doesn't do anything at this time
      ##checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(self.root, text="Keep me logged in")
      ##checkbox.grid(row=3, columnspan=2)

      logbtn = tk.Button(self.root, text="Login", command = self._login_btn_clickked)
      logbtn.grid(row=9, columnspan=2)
      myButton = tk.Button(self.root, text="Exit",command = self.buttonPushed)
      myButton.grid(row=10)

      self.root.mainloop()

   def buttonPushed(self):
      self.root.destroy()

   def _login_btn_clickked(self):
      #print("Clicked")
      username = self.entry_1.get()
      password = self.entry_2.get()

      #print(username, password)

      if username == "test" and password == "test":
          print "OK login"
          #box.showinfo("Login info", "Welcome Tester")
          #button1 = ttk.Button(self.root, text="Please click, Welcome to login!!!",
          #           command=lambda: self.controller.show_frame(StartPage))
          #button1.pack()
      else:
          #box.showerror("Login failed", "Incorrect username")
          print "Error"

LP=LoginPage()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring all of the other problems with your code, I had the same problem the other day. When you call `self.root.destroy()`, Tkinter will exit the `root.mainloop`. Then after the place where you call `root.mainloop` you probably have a call to `root.destroy`. This means you are trying to destroy twice, which is what is causing the error. One way to deal with this is to let the `Exception` pass silently (though in general this is not good practice):

```
try:
    root.destroy()
except:
    pass
```

I may be wrong, but this is the only thing I can imagine is causing this error.

Answer (score 1):

If applicable, `root.quit()` might fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually occurs when you have more than 2 mainloops.
Do nothing more than:

```
import sys
```

and then create a button to exit:

```
B=tk.Button(self.root,text="quit",command=lambda:sys.exit())
B.grid()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mistakenly destroy a root window that is already destroyed or not created yet then this kind of error occurs

Answer (score 0):

you need to destroy the def as they will keep repeating. Use "your def"`.destroy()` to prevent this error from happening. I had the same issue. it was one of the def causing it for me and destroying this def in an `if` statement solved my issue